# How to get user using email and password firebase with nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

how can I get a user data using firebase authentication with email and password of an user?

the only way I was able to capture the user was to use the

`firebase.auth() function.getUserByEmail(email)`

but I don't find how to perform that call passing the email and password of the user, any help with this question?

my source code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');
const inquirer = require('inquirer')
const serviceAccount = require('...')
var currentUser;
var userProfile;

var config = {
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "...",
    databaseURL: "...",
    projectId: "...",
    storageBucket: "...",
    messagingSenderId: "..."
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);


    let server = app.listen('8081', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("App listening on port " + "8081");

        var authentication = [
            {
                type: 'input',
                name: 'email',
                message: "Type your email:",
            },
            {
                type: 'password',
                name: 'password',
                message: "Type your password:",
            },
        ]

    inquirer.prompt(authentication).then(answers => {
        console.log(`Hello! The application is starting!`)
        startCrawler(answers['email'], answers['password'])
    })

    async () => {
        await firebase.auth().getUserByEmail(email) //Here where I want to grab the user with email and password
            .then((user) => {
                currentUser = user.toJSON();
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Email or password invalid!');
            });

        if (!currentUser) { return };
    }

});
```

Comment: You can't get a plaintext password for a user.  That's a security problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to sign the user in on a Node.js app that uses the Firebase Admin SDK. The Firebase Admin SDK doesn't have the concept of a signed in user. If you need that, consider using the regular Firebase SDK for web applications.

Also see my answer here: [Firebase Admin SDK to Log user in from Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51815987/firebase-admin-sdk-to-log-user-in-from-server)