# Firebase anonymous signin with python flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask

Does firebase support signInAnonymously when using python? Turns out I've been checking the documentation and not seeing any support. I'm using flask and want to implement anonymous sign.

I've already added firebase to my flask project but I don't see anonymous signin option on `firebase.auth()`

```
from firebase import Firebase

credentials = {
      "apiKey": "",
      "authDomain": "",
      "databaseURL": "",
      "projectId": "",
      "storageBucket": "",
      "messagingSenderId": "",
    }

firebase = Firebase(credentials)

auth = firebase.auth()

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login successful')
        # want to use auth here to sigin the user anonymously
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('login.html',  title='Sign In', form=form)
```

Any suggestions on implementing anonymous signin using python flask?

Answer (score 0):

With the Firebase Admin SDK, you can create an **anonymous** Firebase user account, but it does not provide an API for user sign-in. This is generally handled on the client-side.

For a workaround, see: [Firebase Admin SDK to Log user in from Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51815987/1164465)

## Create an Anonymous User with Firebase Admin SDK

Be sure that the `Anonymous` sign-in provider is enabled in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) `> Your Project > Authentication > Sign-in method`

[image: Firebase Console Sign-in method]

In your Python code, after you have [initialized the SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#initialize_the_sdk), call [firebase_admin.auth.create_user(**kwargs)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#create_user) with no arguments.

```
import firebase_admin.auth as auth

anonymous_user = auth.create_user()
```

If you check the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) `> Your Project > Authentication > Users`, the new Anonymous user will be listed.

[image: Firebase Anonymous User]